# Order by ascending / descending with certain condition in single query

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a table as below:

```
+-----+-------------+
| id  | status_code |
+-----+-------------+
|  1  |         200 |
|  2  |         301 |
|  3  |         404 |
|  4  |         404 |
|  5  |           0 |
|  6  |         200 |
|  7  |         200 |
+-----+-------------+
```

How to i get the result below in single query?

1) Order by status code descending but 0 at the top of the result.

```
+-----+-------------+
| id  | status_code |
+-----+-------------+
|  5  |           0 |
|  4  |         404 |
|  3  |         404 |
|  2  |         301 |
|  7  |         200 |
|  6  |         200 |
|  1  |         200 |
+-----+-------------+
```

2) Order by status code ascending but 0 at the end of the result.

```
+-----+-------------+
| id  | status_code |
+-----+-------------+
|  1  |         200 |
|  6  |         200 |
|  7  |         200 |
|  2  |         301 |
|  3  |         404 |
|  4  |         404 |
|  5  |           0 |
+-----+-------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get `0` at the top:

```
ORDER BY status_code = 0 DESC, status_code DESC
```

To get `0` at the bottom:

```
ORDER BY status_code = 0 ASC, status_code ASC
```

This works because comparison operators return `0` for `false` and `1` for `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Just include multiple keys.  In MySQL, this is easy:

```
order by (status_code = 0) desc, status_code desc
```

for the first case.

```
order by (status_code = 0) asc, status_code asc
```

in the second.

How does this work?  MySQL treats a boolean expression as an integer in a numeric context, with 0 being false and 1 being true.  So, `(status = 0)` turns into 0 or 1.  The `asc` and `desc` just determine which goes first.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:-

```
select * from yourtable 
order by (status_code = 0) desc, status_code desc
```